# Getting parent thread id if process executed from thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am not sure if it is possible but I guess it worth asking anyway.
I have a static size thread pool. Main thread will execute a lot of async jobs and any job can execute another job using CompletableFuture and static thread pool.

```
public void doSomething()
{
    asyncCallA();
}

public void asyncCallA(){
   asyncCallB();
   asyncCallC();
}
```

Question: While processing an asyncCallC() is it possible to identify `Main` thread id?

Comment: What do you intend to do with it?

Comment: Threads don't have a parent-child relationship. If asyncCallC() literally needs to access some other thread, then you would probably need to store that thread object somewhere that asyncCallC() could get to it. You should consider describing at a higher level what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: In a hight concurrent web service which does not have a request scope I am trying to share a global object. It needs to be accessable by any thread.

Comment: If you want a global object, what do you need the main thread for?

Comment: If I just create a global object it will be shared across all requests. What I want to have a way to distinguish every request into seperate storage. So I am thinking of having a Map<ThreadId, Object>.

Comment: Can you use a custom `ThreadPoolExecutor`? We did this, in order to make scope info about the user session available when running background tasks from the UI thread. If you can, I can give you a small code example.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change how ThreadPool is structured. \

Answer (score 0):

If you give more code it might be easier to propose a solution but there are several ways to achieve that (If i understand the goal properly)

For example you can have a reference to the parent thread in the thread class. And when you create new threads pass that reference. Something like

```
class A extends Thread
 {
     Thread parent;
     public A(Thread parent)
     {
       this.parent=parent;
     }
 }
```

Might not be the best way but this way you have reference to the thread that called yours. Then you should access it in a synchronized block.  This way you can iterate through the nodes of the thread tree ;)

If you just want the main thread you can define a static variable and since it is static it is the same in all threads. For example in st

```
static AClass mainThreadObject=this;
```

and then in the other threads you access it by AClass .mainThreadObject

Comment: I am not creating a new threads. They are coming from Thread pool

Comment: if you just want a global object why not create it static? Might not be the best solution but it is global after all and shared between the threads

Comment: Its tricky in my case because: Webservice does not support request scope therefore that global object will be shared across all requests. I don't what that, or at least I want to find a way to distinguish it somehow. ThreadId was an idea.